# Problem with libbson version for mongocxx driver [Windows OS]

Tags: windows, mongo-cxx-driver

Trying to build mongocxx driver. 
I have installed mongoc driver without problems in path c:\mongo-c-driver (ver. 1.14.0). 
After running:

```
cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-cxx-driver
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\mongo-c-driver
    -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/Zc:__cplusplus"
```

got an error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI3xm.png)

Don't know why but in in file libbson-1.0-config.cmake I have lines like:

```
set (BSON_MAJOR_VERSION 0)
set (BSON_MINOR_VERSION 0)
set (BSON_MICRO_VERSION 0)
set (BSON_VERSION 0.0.0)
```

and in libbson-1.0-config-version.cmake:

```
set (PACKAGE_VERSION 0.0.0)
```

I Think that here's possible reason but changing these lines manually doesn't fix the problem (try with 3.2 and 3.4 version of mongocxx driver).

Comment: I believe this is due to an issue in how you have built the C driver. You need to provide some metadata to ensure it knows its version. I've pinged the internal team that maintains the C driver with a link to this question, since I don't know exactly how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CDRIVER-3022 for instructions on how to avoid this issue. The TL;DR is that the zip file that GitHub automatically produces for a release doesn't contain required version information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works with 1.13.1 version that contains VERSION_CURRENT and VERSION_RELEASED - both statically contain the string 1.13.1. and version 1.14.0 does not contain those files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an official MongoDB article that showcases how to build and run mongocxx (MongoDB C++ Driver) on Windows - [Getting Started with MongoDB and C++](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/getting-started-mongodb-c/)